# Extension of a local isometry to the tangent bundle with Sasaki metric and completeness

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $f\colon (M, g)\to (N,h)$ be a local isometry between two $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds without boundary. Consider the Sasaki metrics $g_S$ and $h_S$ on the tangent bundles $TM$ and $TN$, respectively.

*Question 1:* Is the derivative map $df\colon (TM, g_S)\to (TN, h_S)$ a local isometry?

*Question 2:* If $(M,g)$ is complete, is $(TM,g_S)$ complete?

*Note:* I started learning the Sasaki metric recently. The following article tells that if $f\colon M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism, then $df\colon TM\to TM$ is an isometry if and only if $f$ is an isometry.

*Reference:*

Shigeo Sasaki. “On the differential geometry of tangent bundles of Riemannian manifolds”. In: Tohoku Math. J. (2) 10 (1958), pp. 338–354. ISSN: 0040-8735.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to both of your questions are positive. For the first one, there is a paper of Satoh which computes the curvature for a Sasaki metric (with general connection), and from these calculations it follows that if the two metrics are locally isometric, then their Levi-Civita connections are  identical (in some neighborhood) and thus the Sasaki metrics are locally the same as well [1].

I don't know of a published reference for the second question, but [here is a proof from StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4156094/585060).

[1] *Satoh, Hiroyasu*, [**Almost Hermitian structures on tangent bundles**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10824), Suh, Young Jin (ed.) et al., Proceedings of the 11th international workshop on differential geometry, Taegu, Korea, November 9–11, 2006. Taegu: Kyungpook National University. 105-118 (2007). [ZBL1125.53022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1125.53022).